# How to deploy a docker app to production without using Docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

I have heard it said that

> Docker compose is designed for development NOT for production.

But I have seen people use Docker compose on production with bind mounts. Then pull the latest changes from github and it appears live in production without the need to rebuild. But **others** say that you need to `COPY . .` for production and rebuild.

1. But how does this work? Because in `docker-compose.yaml` you can specify `depends-on` which doesn't start one container until the other is running. If I don't use `docker-compose` in production then what about this? How would I push my docker-compose to production (I have 4 services / 4 images that I need to run). With `docker-compose up -d` it is so easy.
2. How do I build each image individually?
3. How can I copy these images to my production server to run them (in correct order)? I can't even **find** the build images on my machine anywhere.

This is my **docker-compose.yaml** file that works great for development

```
version: '3'
services:

  # Nginx client server
  nginx-client:
    container_name: nginx-client
    build:
        context: .                  
    restart: always
    stdin_open: true  
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true  
    ports:
      - 28874:3000
    volumes:
      - ./client:/var/www
      - /var/www/node_modules
    networks:
      - app-network


  # MySQL server for the server side app
  mysql-server:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: mysql-server
    restart: always
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "16427:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: BcGH2Gj41J5VF1
      MYSQL_DATABASE: todo
    volumes:
      - ./docker/mysql-server/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - app-network


  # Nginx server for the server side app
  nginx-server:
    container_name: nginx-server
    image: nginx:1.17-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 49691:80
    volumes:
      - ./server:/var/www
      - ./docker/nginx-server/etc/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
    - php-server
    - mysql-server
    networks:
      - app-network


  # PHP server for the server side app
  php-server:
    build:
      context: .        
      dockerfile: ./docker/php-server/Dockerfile
    container_name: php-server
    restart: always
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: php
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./server:/var/www
      - ./docker/php-server/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
      - /var/www/vendor
    networks:
      - app-network
    depends_on:
      - mysql-server


# Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you build the docker images? I assume you don't plan using a registry, therefore you'll have to:

- give an image name to all services
- build the docker images somewhere (a CI/CD server, locally, it does not really matter)
- save the images in a file
- zip the file
- export the zipped file remotely
- on the server, unzip and load

I'd create a script for this. Something like this:

````sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e

docker-compose build

docker save -o images.tar "$( grep  "image: .*" docker-compose.yml | awk '{ print $2 }' )"
gzip images.tar

scp images.tar.gz myserver:~

ssh myserver ./load_images.sh
-----

on myserver, the load_images.sh would look like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -f images.tar.gz ] ; then
    echo "no file"
    exit 1
fi

gunzip images.tar.gz
docker load -i images.tar
````

Then you'll have to create the docker commands to emulate the docker-compose configuration (I won't go there since it's nothing difficult but it's boring and I'm not feeling like writing that). How do you simulate the `depends_on`? Well, you'll have to start each container singularly so you'll either prepare another script or you'll do it manually.

---

About using docker-compose on production:

There's not really a big issue about using docker-compose on production as soon as you do it properly. e.g. some of my production setups tends to look like this:

- docker-compose.yml
- docker-compose.dev.yml
- docker-compose.prd.yml

The devs will use `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml $cmd` while on production you'll use `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prd.yml $cmd`.

Taking you file as an example, I'd move all `volumes`, `ports`, `tty` and `stdin_open` subsections from docker-compose.yml to docker-compose.dev.yml. e.g.
the docker-compose.dev.yml would look like this:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  nginx-client:
    stdin_open: true
    ports:
      - 28874:3000
    volumes:
      - ./client:/var/www
      - /var/www/node_modules

  mysql-server:
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "16427:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/mysql-server/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf

  nginx-server:
    ports:
      - 49691:80
    volumes:
      - ./server:/var/www
      - ./docker/nginx-server/etc/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d

  php-server:
    restart: always
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./server:/var/www
      - ./docker/php-server/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
      - /var/www/vendor
```

on production, the docker-compose you'll have the strictly required `port` subsections, define a production environment file where the required passwords are stored (the file will be only on the production server, not in git), etc etc.

Actually, you have so many different approaches you can take.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, docker-compose is used as a container-orchestration tool on development. There are several other production-grade container orchestration tools available on most of the popular hosting services like GCP and AWS. Kubernetes is by far the most popular and most commonly used.

Based on the services used in your docker-compose, it advisable to not use it directly on production. Running a mysql container can lead to issues with data loss as containers are meant to be temporary. It is better to opt for a managed MySQL service like RDS instead. Similarly nginx is also better set up with any reverse-proxy/load-balancer services that your hosting service provides.

When it comes to building the images you can utilise your CI/CD pipeline to build these images from their respective Dockerfiles, and then push to a image registry of your choice and let your hosting service pick up the image and deploy it with th e container-orchestration tool that your hosting service provides.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a lightweight production environment, using Compose is probably fine.  Other answers here have hinted at more involved tools, that have advantages like supporting multiple-host clusters and zero-downtime deployments, but they are much more involved.

One core piece missing from your description is an **image registry**.  Docker Hub fits this role, if you want to use it; major cloud providers have one; even GitHub has a container registry now (for public repositories); or you can run your own.  This addresses a couple of your problems: (2) you `docker build` the images locally (or on a dedicated continuous-integration system) and `docker push` them to the registry, then (3) you `docker pull` the images on the production system, or let Docker do it on its own.

A good practice that goes along with this is to give each build a unique tag, perhaps a date stamp or commit ID.  This makes it very easy to upgrade (or downgrade) by changing the tag and re-running `docker-compose up`.

For this you'd change your `docker-compose.yml` like:

```yaml
services:
  nginx-client:
    # No `build:`
    image: registry.example.com/nginx:${NGINX_TAG:latest}
  php-server:
    # No `build:`
    image: registry.example.com/php:${PHP_TAG:latest}
```

And then you can update things like:

```sh
docker build -t registry.example.com/nginx:20201101 ./nginx
docker build -t registry.example.com/php:20201101 ./php
docker push registry.example.com/nginx:20201101 registry.example.com/php:20201101

ssh production-system.example.com \
  NGINX_TAG=20201101 PHP_TAG=20201101 docker-compose up -d
```

You can use multiple `docker-compose.yml` files to also use `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose push` for your custom images, with a development-only overlay file.  There is [an example in the Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#example-use-case).

Do not separately copy your code; it's contained in the image.  Do not bind-mount local code over the image code.  Especially do not use an anonymous volume to hold libraries, since this will completely ignore any updates in the underlying image.  These are good practices in development too, since if you replace everything interesting in an image with volume mounts then it doesn't really have any relation to what you're running in production.

You will need to separately copy the configuration files you reference and the `docker-compose.yml` itself to the target system, and take responsibility for backing up the database data.

Finally, I'd recommend removing unnecessary options from the `docker-compose.yml` file (don't manually specify `container_name:`, use the Compose-provided `default` network, prefer specifying the `command:` in an image, and so on).  That's not essential but it can help trim down the size of the YAML file.